# Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

When I start my Expo project with

```html
expo start --clear --localhost --dev
```

Expo is starting the Metro Bundler and a short time later it is up and running. => "Metro Bundler ready"
But after maybe 30-60 seconds this notification pops up:

[image]

I've already tried reinstalling nodejs and expo. I've also tried just running 'expo start'. But nothing worked for me. 
The only error I get is:

```html
[08:07:54] Could not access packager status at http://127.0.0.1:19001/status. Are you sure the packager is running and reachable?
```

The funny thing is that the first time I tried 'expo start' it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, use `ipconfig` on `cmd`, get the ip address of the network you are connected to and run, using my ip address as an example, run

```
set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.200.63
```

Answer (score 0):

use "sudo npm install"
then use "sudo expo start"

I solved my problem using these commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).